# Including libraries in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-s3

I'm using Codeigniter for my website and I want to `include()` the Amazon S3 PHP SDK library. Where in Codeigniter's directories should I place the folder of files for the S3 SDK library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

```
application/libraries
```